# Mongodb nodejs driver skip() does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The following code always returns the same documents. The **req.query.skip** keeps incremeting by 10, still the same set of documents are printed. Also there are more than 1000's of documents.

```
Collection.find({}).skip(req.query.skip).limit(10);

var imageIdArray = [];
cursor.each(function(err, item) {
if (item == null) { // end
    console.log(imageIdArray);
    res.write(JSON.stringify(imageIdArray));
    res.end();
} else {
    imageIdArray.push(item._id);
}
});
```

The skip() function looks like it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns the same documents because **[skip](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#skip)** requires a number as an argument and the `req.query.skip` value is a string, you need to parse it to integer first then pass it as the skip parameter:

```
var skip = parseInt(req.query.skip),
    cursor = Collection.find({}).skip(skip).limit(10);

var imageIdArray = [];
cursor.each(function(err, item) {
    if (item == null) { // end
        console.log(imageIdArray);
        res.write(JSON.stringify(imageIdArray));
        res.end();
    } else {
        imageIdArray.push(item._id);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. after updating the mongodb-nodejs driver from 1.4 to 2.0 version it showed as warning message.